# Unreadable beeline query results

Tags: hive, impala, beeline

## Environment

Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.13.0 by Apache Hive

## Context

I need to execute some select statements with beeline and process the results later on.

However, the output of beeline is not readable, not even "processable".

## Code

I execute the following command:

```
beeline -u $IMPALA_URL -n writer -p writer --outputformat=tsv2 -e "select * from bas_fca.table_info"  > results 2> errors
```

## Output

The content of the `results` file:

```
-----------------------------
table   type    creation_date
```

The content of the `errors` file:

```
2021-06-14 14:39:03,580 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.
scan complete in 2ms
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://mynodes:21050/
Connected to: Impala (version 2.10.0-cdh5.13.0)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.1.0-cdh5.13.0)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
cu_ddi.activ_from_api
cu_ddi.cumul_from_api
cu_ddi.data_from_api
cu_ddi.envoi_from_api
cu_ddi.inscript
cu_ddi.tmp
No rows selected (0.098 seconds)
Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.13.0 by Apache Hive
Closing: 0: jdbc:hive2://mynodes:21050/
```

## Expected output

When running above query in Hue, I have the following results:

```
cu_ddi.activ_from_api   EXTERNAL_TABLE  2020-01-29 16:13:18 
cu_ddi.cumul_from_api   EXTERNAL_TABLE  2020-01-22 09:04:47 
cu_ddi.data_from_api    EXTERNAL_TABLE  2020-01-21 15:05:58 
cu_ddi.envoi_from_api   EXTERNAL_TABLE  2020-01-29 16:12:25 
cu_ddi.inscript EXTERNAL_TABLE  2019-10-25 11:35:03 
cu_ddi.tmp  MANAGED_TABLE   2020-01-21 15:06:40
```

## Questions

- Why do I only have the table names ?
- Why are the incomplete results written to STDERR ?
- How to have the results with a processable format (CSV, etc.) ?

## Edit 1

- Requested by Koushik Roy.

Output of:

```
beeline -u $IMPALA_URL -n writer -p writer -e "select * from bas_fca.table_info" > results

cat results

+--------+-------+----------------+--+
| table  | type  | creation_date  |
+--------+-------+----------------+--+
+--------+-------+----------------+--+
```

Comment: For impala data dump, you can use `inpala-shell -o output_file -q "query"`. beeline should work with hive. Output - i am not sure about the format you are using. can you use a simple format and see how its behaving `beeline -u jdbc:hive2://host_ip/ -f hive.hql >output.txt`

Comment: @KoushikRoy I added the requested output. I'll look into impala-shell. I did not know I had it available on my cluster.